# Picasso not possible to have both error message and on success?

Tags: android, picasso

Is it possible to have both some sort of onImageLoaded and onImageLoadFailed with error cause (exception) in picasso?

My image load was failing on a particular image when my code used the Callback style:

```
      picasso.load(imageUrl)
      .into(
          imageView
          new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
              imageLoadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              imageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
              Log.e(TAG, "Image load failed", new Throwable());
              imageLoadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
          });
```

To debug this I add Picasso.Listener to the builder for onImageLoadFailed 
      Picasso picasso = new Builder(getApplicationContext())
          .listener(
              (Picasso p, Uri u,Exception e) -> {
                imageLoadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.e(TAG, "Image load failed", e);
              }).build();

...but it was NOT getting called. I removed the Callback from my subsequent picasso call and now it's getting called! great. So how do I get notified now onImageLoadSuccess? Is it impossible to have both?

Here's my latest code that works but I don't have a callback for when the image successfully is loaded:

```
  Picasso picasso = new Builder(getApplicationContext())
      .listener(
          (Picasso p, Uri u,Exception e) -> {
            imageLoadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.e(TAG, "Image load failed", e);
          }).build();


  picasso.load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Tried to use this overloaded variant of into() ? into(android.widget.ImageView target,
                 Callback callback)

Comment: yes as clearly shown in the first code example. callback onError has no exception

Comment: In the meaniwhile I solved by switching to Glide. Serendipitously it also solved the underlining image download issue.